# Does executeScript still work after change window.location.href

Tags: google-chrome-extension

when i change the window.location.href,the executeScript  didn't work.why is this?
   manifest.json is

```
{
  "name": "Page Redder",
  "description": "Make the current page red",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab","*://*/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Make this page red"
  },
  "background": {
     "scripts": ["jquery-1.11.1.js","background.js"]
 },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js is

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{code:'window.location.href="http://www.google.com"'},function(){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"test.js"}, function() {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    }
    });
  }); 
});
```

test.js is

```
alert("hello work")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the file in the second `executeScript` is being injected after the code of the first `executeScript` has been *executed*, but *before* the `window.location.href` call has finished. See for yourself: add a breakpoint on the line calling the second `chrome.tabs.executeScript`, click your browser action and then wait for the page to load before resuming - the popup will work.

One way to solve this is to add a `tabs.onUpdated` listener. Then, when you click your browser action store what the tabId was. Inside the `tabs.onUpdated` listener you can execute `test.js` if the updated `tabId` matches the `tabId` set in your browser action. Quick example:

```
var activeTabId;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: 'window.location.href="http://www.google.com"'}, function (){
    activeTabId = tab.id;
  }); 
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if(tabId === activeTabId) {
    activeTabId = null; //To prevent executing the script multiple times
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file:"test.js"});
  }
});
```